# Java Eclipse exporting game with source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, export

i'm trying to export my game with bunch of music. when i exported game with music(file size is 300mb(resources folder is about 300 mb size))

when i run the jar then i hear no sound. i tried with cmd it shows following error:

[image]

**Any Help?**

**Edit**

**SoundManager Class:**

```
package com.memequickie.sound;

import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class SoundManager {
    Clip clip;
    public boolean playSound(File sound) {
        boolean ended = false;
        try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
            clip.start();
            if(clip.getMicrosecondLength() == clip.getMicrosecondPosition()) 
            {
                ended = true;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ended;
    }

    public void stopSound() {
        clip.stop();
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I tried inputstream and still can't get it to working.
[image]

Comment: You cannot access jar entries as files.

Comment: What does your `SoundManager` class look like?

Comment: Added code for `SoundManager` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File)` **expects** `Music6.wav` as a real file, **not** as a zipped file **inside the JAR**.

If you want to ship your audio files inside the JAR, you have to use `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)` with the [audio file as `InputStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389418/6505250) wrapped in a `BufferedInputStream` instead.

Comment: Please see Edit section in my post.

Comment: If you need a file (because you want to mark and reset the audio, which seems not supported with `InputStream`s), you only have the two options to not pack the audio files into the JAR file or to unpack the audio file temporarily before using it.

Comment: I just want to play music files back. no fancy stuff.

Comment: Use `new BufferedInputStream(InputStream)` instead directly the `InputStream` from `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.